# In HC12 is it possible to compare 2 registers directly?

Tags: assembly, 68hc12

If I've loaded a value into register X and one into register Y, and I want to compare them... usually I have to do something like:

```
ldx value_1
ldy value_2
pshy
cpx 0,sp
ins
```

But that's 3 operations for the compare. Is there not a way to do this directly? I've tried `cmp 0,y` and cmp `y`, but those don't do what I want.

Is this just something I'll have to live with?

Thanks,

z.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For X and Y, I think yes, you have to load them first.

If you can use A and B though, you might be able to use SBA. That would subtract the contents of B from A, setting your zero and other flags just like in a comparison.

Comment: As I suspected... alas I am working with 16-bit values that I need to compare. Thanks for the quick reply! HC12 stuff is hard to google (all the answers really are in the manual... but sometimes you want a second opinion).